# How do I find peers for a ropsten "light" node?

Tags: ropsten, light-clients, peers

I'm using `geth` to spin a simple light node on ropsten. I'm running

```
geth --ropsten --syncmode "light" console
```

And it gets stuck after

```
INFO [06-18|11:05:26.682] New local node record                    seq=16 id=myid ip=73.___.___.57 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [06-18|11:05:27.596] Mapped network port                      proto=udp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPNP IGDv1-IP1"
INFO [06-18|11:05:28.760] Mapped network port                      proto=tcp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPNP IGDv1-IP1"
```

I read online that the bootnodes for ropsten are often down, so I found supposed ppers online from [here](https://gist.github.com/rfikki/ec233552af9f71eb9a00f6cbc4dd7b0d). So, in the console I added:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://0b64924d478abaf6900ffed857dc066b29e6a9498c8a6604a159555bd08fe1ccf3c2cefdbd625b0e7cf93b49c3cc6d6e412a5cde92b4a7d2b8bfd6f10d56511e@136.144.129.222:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://4fee548ed37a0aa07101479f0fb8672573b1396b100869eb8a6db77e05b8780293376c0bdd8ed41bfb503e2df20b0702c7b61ff795d9aa3eedf9d70b952643eb@34.195.230.169:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://5b190dc2848404a46ac47413c35e68e73fd5e4eb4fd681ed511ef3280d47169e703990ecd4e67a3c1eaa4e4788d56d182b3c62f32628bcc9fc772f6568ffc19e@104.236.178.16:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://72c074af1e24caaa6904503fa88c3ef2881d319bebb32dbe8282f4be3dab07ffd873970642a5ca7d8f03e3e14b8aea080811828c5ffbd183c94778ef53c904e2@188.214.30.138:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://a9e72b8b22f5f5ca858588a378af9f2214ac81f65e53b93e0e2bf00e6d36d353ad71a6f28b916155548922cf14401e4ab2950ec2a7a6870a512890e214dcbc76@139.59.155.74:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://c86ed8addd5f8356e4a3aad415805feb39e0e0e36903be1968bc71abbbd6612437454277cbf39915e3ebf3b9804e7f86644b68e115d56866d4744b69ed67bbc4@173.199.118.174:30303");
admin.addPeer("enode://e8e493e5f11b4275211259e6f86b24b9786f61667fabdd8be4bd9dd26a39083b38bad3f2a443cd968bbf1a87496d62f92a1d4788168b1891b02d35d9d9787065@107.21.14.206:30303");
```

I also added [this one](https://gist.github.com/rfikki/a83be7f0e12d03c21a08e217164341a5) which supposedly is for lightclients.

```
admin.addPeer("enode://fafe7982ebe514913d295bc088fae3a2678aaf5783463421e7d2c22e1d2f363c2832143ecdd4a2270d14c2d0af80688e5ed0dce137e32812db6699c5e063c77e@167.71.164.90:30303");
```

Nothing... my output keeps looking for peers, with not luck:

```
INFO [06-18|11:07:51.740] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=7 static=10
INFO [06-18|11:08:09.267] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3 static=10
INFO [06-18|11:08:26.743] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=7 static=10
INFO [06-18|11:08:44.266] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3 static=10
INFO [06-18|11:09:01.747] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=7 static=10
INFO [06-18|11:09:19.273] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3 static=10
INFO [06-18|11:09:36.752] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=7 static=10
```

Is there any reliable way to connect a light node to ropsten?